# Caffeine cache does not work with String parameter as a key

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, caffeine-cache

I have a service class called TeamService annotated as @Service.

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheConfig.TEAM, key = "#root.methodName.concat(#nationality == null ? '' : #nationality )")
    public List<Team> getTeamList(String nationality ) {
       return teamFinder.getTeams().stream()
             .filter(team -> team.getNationality().equals(nationality))
             .toList();
}
```

Team finder is an external service. It finds all teams. Cachable works correctly if nationality parameter passed as null, but if I pass a value like ENG, then the cache does not work. Each time I send a request to this method, even if my nationality parameter is the same, the method starts, calls the teamFinder service then filter the results rather than return the result from cache. I have tried to use only nationality parameter as the key, it still did not work correctly. What is wrong for my code?

Could you tell me how can I use both method name and the nationality parameter as key value of the cache?

- My caffeine version is 3.1.6
- java version is 17
- spring-boot-starter and spring-boot-starter-cache 3.1.2

Comment: are you using `weakKeys`? That's incompatible with Spring Cache

Comment: Yes, when I check Caching Config, I see that this is used. When I removed it, my keys worked correctly. Thanks for this great help.